# Open URL in Chrome in the same or current tab

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I have an internal web app that is opened from a Windows process. I need the application/url to be opened in the current open tab or the tab already open for the app. In IE this can be done by referencing the window name, but I can't seem to find a similar option or command line argument from Chrome.

The goal is to prevent having the same application/website open in multiple tabs requiring the user to close the previous browser window.

Answer (score 0):

Plugins are a solution. I have not found this ability built into Google Chrome, and corporate IT may block these plugins on your system meaning it is not a solution for your system.

A number of plugins I found, sorted in order of most users, and a related SuperUser question:

- [Clutter Free](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clutter-free-prevent-dupl/iipjdmnoigaobkamfhnojmglcdbnfaaf?hl=en-GB)
- [Duplicate Tab Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/duplicate-tab-helper/oaceoebbkmkgfjhmngdinoclnionlgoh?hl=en-GB)
- [Unique Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unique-tabs/cicbejncjmbkbahiicbiflndmhbcgibk?hl=en)
- [Fast Duplicate Tab Closer / Fast Unique Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fast-duplicate-tab-closer/dpgkjbmiapibpdjnnoalnlkcmeepocak?hl=en)
- [SuperUser related question](https://superuser.com/questions/240236/extension-for-chrome-that-redirects-you-to-an-existing-tab-if-you-try-and-open-t)